# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load native library

Tags: android, skype, skypedeveloper

Your Healthcare app builds and works (connection establishes without problems) fine.

Then I took all classes and layouts and other settings from your Healthcare app and put them into my own project. My project compiles and builds without errors.

But! when I try to start conversation my app crashes in SkypeCall.java with error message:

```
"
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load native library
at com.microsoft.office.sfb.appsdk.Application.LoadNativeLibrary(Application.java:98)
at com.microsoft.office.sfb.appsdk.Application.initialize(Application.java:63)
at com.microsoft.office.sfb.appsdk.Application.getInstance(Application.java:112)
at kz.altyn.portalmobile.skype.SkypeCall.onCreate(SkypeCall.java:68)
"
```

at this part of the code

```
"
68: mConversation = startToJoinMeeting();
69: mConversation.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new ConversationPropertyChangeListener());
"
```

Comment: When you say "your Healthcare app", who do you believe you are addressing? Stack Overflow is mainly read by software professionals and hobbyists who volunteer to help people with their tech problems - we don't have a Healthcare app.

Comment: @halfer My bad. Sorry

Comment: OK, would you amend your post to indicate what Healthcare app you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact layout of your project, I would suspect you have copied the information over, but may have missed the libraries used by the App SDK.  IF you look at the GitHub sample for the [HealthcareApp](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples/tree/master/HealthcareApp) you will notice that it does contain a step for copying the SDK libraries into the project.

> The samples already include local references to the Skype for Business libraries. After you clone the repository, you need to copy the libraries into the sample project folders at: [your local repository]\skype-android-app-sdk-samples\HealthcareApp\app\libs.

I would also make sure that you have correclty added the libraries into your Gradle file as listed in the [AppSDK-GettingStarted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/gettingstarted).

Comment: I did everything as written in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/gettingstarted.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

Here is the Android monitor showing error